# When does adjoining a single root of an irreducible polynomial generate the splitting field?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose for example we were in $\mathbb{Q}$, the rationals, and wanted to find the splitting field of some polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ for which we know there exists an algebraic root $\alpha$. When is the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ a splitting field for $f$? For example, the polynomial $x^p-1$ has algebraic solutions $\beta = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$ as well as any power less than $p-1$ of $\beta$ ($p$ prime). The field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ is therefore a splitting field of $x^p-1$ achieved by adjoining a single root of $x^p-1$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. What conditions must hold on $f$ for this to be the case?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. First, have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions. Second, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you think it is true for $x^3-2$ ?

Comment: @GEdgar I suppose it's not since this has complex roots so if you adjoined only $2^{1/3}$ then you wouldn't have the other 2 solutions but if you adjoined any of the complex solutions you'd have generated the whole splitting field no?

Comment: No, adjoining any one root is not the whole splitting field..

Comment: @AdamPaquette: You are correct that adding $\sqrt[3]{2}$ alone does not yield the splitting field. That tells you the splitting field is of degree greater than $3$ (and since it must be of degree dividing $3!$, it is of degree $6$). As adding a single root, no matter which one, only gives you an extension of degree $3$, you cannot get the splitting field by adding a single root, period.